# Xamarin forms Air Watch AWSDK Android Error

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, airwatch

We see error with new Xamarin forms project, when we add AWSDK nuget package. Is this SDK applicable for Xamarin forms?

AWSDK Url : https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/awsdk

Error \users\name\Source\Repos\App5\App5\App5.Android\obj\Debug\lp\2\jl\res\values\values.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'preferenceTheme'. App5.Android c:\users\narendra_k_meena\Source\Repos\App5\App5\App5.And[image]roid\c

Comment: .Android\obj\Debug\lp\2\jl\res\values\values.xml:1: error: Attribute "fontStyle" has already been defined 
.Android\obj\Debug\lp\2\jl\res\values\values.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'preferenceTheme'. Av4\awsdk_qr_code_black.png: libpng warninc:\gus:ers\n areindCCP: Not recora_kg_nmizinge kena\Sounorcew\Reposn \App5\sRApp5\AppG5B profi.Anle dthrat has beoiden\ edobj\itedDebug\ App5.Android c:\users\user\Source\Repos\App5\App5\App5.Android\c

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and resolved it by downgrading all Xamarin.Android packages. AWSDK is compatible with with Major release 25. If you use Xamarin.Android packages with Major release 26, i get this error. 
I use Xamarin.Android Version 25.4.0.2 now and it works fine. Before downgrading i used Version 26.0.2.

To downgrade uninstall all Xamarin.Android packages and then install the older Version.